# Redux: No overload matches this call

Tags: angular, typescript, redux

I'm working with Angular and I'm trying to use Redux to implement JWT authentication and authorization in my project but the "Store.ts" throws an error that states the following:

```
{   "resource":
"/C:/Projects/AngularProjects/CarRental/src/app/redux/store.ts",
"owner": "typescript",  "code": "2769",     "severity": 8,  "message":
"**No overload matches this call.\n  Overload 1 of 2,** '**(reducer:
Reducer<appState, action>, enhancer?: StoreEnhancer<unknown, unknown>
| undefined): Store<appState, action>', gave the following error.\n   
Argument of type '(currentState: appState, action: action) =>
appState' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Reducer<appState,
action>'.\n      Types of parameters 'currentState' and 'state' are
incompatible.**\n        Type 'appState | undefined' is not assignable
to type 'appState'.\n          Type 'undefined' is not assignable to
type 'appState'.\n  **Overload 2 of 2, '(reducer: Reducer<appState,
action>, preloadedState?:** { user: { userId?: number | undefined;
firstName?: string | undefined; lastName?: string | undefined;
identificationNumber?: number | undefined; ... 9 more ...; JwtToken?:
string | undefined; }; cars: { ...; }[]; } | undefined, enhancer?:
StoreEnhancer<...> | undefined): Store<...>', gave the following
error.\n    **Argument of type '(currentState: appState, action: action)
=> appState' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Reducer<appState, action>'."**,    "source": "ts",     "startLineNumber": 5,   "startColumn":
34,     "endLineNumber": 5,     "endColumn": 41 }
```

This is my code for the entire Redux foundation, the models, and service it uses.

**my action-type.ts:**

```
export enum actionType {
    getAllCars,
    Register,
    LogIn,
    LogOut,
    GotError
}
```

**my action.ts**

```
import { actionType } from "./action-type";

export interface action {
    type: actionType;
    payLoad?: any;
}
```

**my app-state.ts**

```
import { carsModel } from '../models/cars.model';
import { userModel } from '../models/user.model';

export class appState {
    public user: userModel = null as any;
    public cars: carsModel[];
    
    public constructor() {
        this.cars = [];
        this.user = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem("user")!);
    }
}
```

**my reducer.ts**

```
import { appState } from "./app-state";
import { actionType } from "./action-type";
import { action } from "./action";

export function reducer(currentState: appState, action: action): appState {

    const newState = { ...currentState };

    switch (action.type) {
        case actionType.getAllCars: newState.cars = action.payLoad;
            break;
        case actionType.Register: newState.user = action.payLoad;
            break;
        case actionType.LogIn: newState.user = action.payLoad;
            sessionStorage.setItem("item", JSON.stringify(newState.user));
            break;
        case actionType.LogOut: newState.user = null as any;
            sessionStorage.removeItem("user");
            break;
    }
    return newState;
}
```

**my store.ts**

```
import { createStore } from "redux";
import { reducer } from './reducer';
import { appState } from './app-state';

export const store = createStore(reducer, new appState());
```

**my userModel.ts**

```
export class userModel {

    constructor (
        public userId?: number, 
        public firstName?: string, 
        public lastName?: string, 
        public identificationNumber?: number,
        public userName?: string,
        public dateOfBirth?: Date,
        public gender?: string,
        public email?: string,
        public passWord?: number,
        public image?: File,
        public imageFileName?: string,
        public roleId?: number,
        public role?: string,
        public JwtToken?: string
        ) {}
}
```

my carsModel.ts

```
export class carsModel {

    static cars: carsModel[];

    constructor (
        public id?: number, 
        public carTypeId?: number, 
        public manufacturer?: string,
        public model?: string,
        public yearOfManufacture?: number,
        public gearBox?: string,
        public name?: string,
        public kilometrage?: number, 
        public usability?: string,
        public availability?: string,
        public vin?: number,
        public branchName?: number,
        public image?: File,
        public imageFileName?: string,
        public cars?: carsModel[]
        ) {}
}
```

**my Auth.service.ts**

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { CredentialsModel } from 'src/app/models/Credentials.model';
import { userModel } from 'src/app/models/user.model';
import { actionType } from 'src/app/redux/action-type';
import { store } from 'src/app/redux/store';
import { environment } from 'src/environments/environment';

@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthService {

    constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

    public async register(user: userModel): Promise<Boolean> {
        const formData = new FormData();
        formData.append("firstName", user.firstName as string);
        formData.append("lastName", user.lastName as string);
        formData.append("identificationNumber", user.identificationNumber?.toString() as any);
        formData.append("userName", user.userName as string);
        formData.append("dateOfBirth", user.dateOfBirth as any);
        formData.append("gender", user.gender as string);
        formData.append("email", user.email as string);
        formData.append("passWord", user.passWord as any);
        formData.append("roleId", user.roleId?.toString() as any);
        formData.append("image", user.image as any, user.image?.name);
        try {
            const registeredUser = await this.http.post<userModel>(environment.authURL + "/Register", formData).toPromise();
            store.dispatch({ type: actionType.Register, registeredUser });
            return true;
        }
        catch (httpErrorResponse) {
            store.dispatch({ type: actionType.GotError, payLoad: httpErrorResponse });
            return false;
        }
    }

    public async Login(credentials: CredentialsModel): Promise<Boolean> {
        try {
            const LoggedInUser = await this.http.post<userModel>(environment.authURL + "/LogIn", credentials).toPromise();
            store.dispatch({ type: actionType.LogIn, LoggedInUser });
            return true;
        }
        catch (httpErrorResponse) {
            store.dispatch({ type: actionType.GotError, payLoad: httpErrorResponse });
            return false;
        }
    }

    public LogOut(): void {
        store.dispatch({ type: actionType.LogOut });
    }
}
```

Can somebody explain why this error keeps popping up?

Thanks again for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to provide a default state in reducer:

**my app-state.ts**

```
import { carsModel } from '../models/cars.model';
import { userModel } from '../models/user.model';

export class appState {
    public user: userModel = null as any;
    public cars: carsModel[];
    
    public constructor() {
        this.cars = [];
        this.user = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem("user")!);
    }
}

export const defaultAppState = new appState();
```

**my reducer.ts**

```
import { appState, defaultAppState } from "./app-state";
import { actionType } from "./action-type";
import { action } from "./action";


export function reducer(currentState: appState = defaultAppState, action: action): appState {
  // omitted
}
```